# Calculating average days without sales in Power Query (M)

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I want to calculate the average days without sales from a table. Im doing a test first with 4 rows, 2 clients each of them with 2 sales and 2 different dates (EDITED: There will be more than 2 dates in real data):

[image: Example Data]

I tried this steps:

```
let
    Origen = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabla1"]}[Content],
    #"Tipo cambiado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Origen,{{"Nombre", type text}, {"Fecha", type datetime}}),
    #"Fecha extraída" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Tipo cambiado",{{"Fecha", DateTime.Date, type date}}),
    #"Filas ordenadas" = Table.Sort(#"Fecha extraída",{{"Nombre", Order.Ascending}, {"Fecha", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Índice agregado" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filas ordenadas", "Índice", 1, 1),
    #"Columnas reordenadas" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Índice agregado",{"Índice", "Nombre", "Fecha"}),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Columnas reordenadas",{{"Índice", "ID"}}),
    #"Calculo Dias" = Table.AddColumn(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado", "Diff", each (try Date.From(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado"[Fecha]{[ID]-2})
    otherwise Date.From([Fecha])) - [Fecha])
in
    #"Calculo Dias"
```

But this doesn´t differentiate between clients and also gives me minus:

[image]

Maybe I should compare rows and match the client but I dont know how to do it. If there is better aproach on doing this, feel free to do so. Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output? 4 and 7 for `Cliente 1` and `Cliente 2`?

Comment: Yes exactly, but there will be more dates, not only 2, then I will calculate average time in days withouth sales in a month for every client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `Nombre` as follows:

[image: Group By]

Then you can define your average days between as a custom column

```
= Number.From([MaxDate]-[MinDate])/([Count]-1)
```

Comment: The problem is there will be more dates, I only made 2 for each client for testing purposes. So the difference between the dates should be calculated for that client and then get the average time without sales in that month.

Comment: This works with as many dates as you want. Summing all the differences between dates is the same as taking the max minus the min.

Comment: Ohh yeah you are right it is the same! I did the test manually with some scenarios, very clever! Thank you!